# java - sharing data between webapp and backend java process

Tags: java

I just want to hear some different opinions about the solution regarding my team's webapp. I have a huge xml (1 or 2G size) which is read into memory which is a temporary solution. The current code spawns a separate thread when the application starts and this thread wakes up to read the xml once a day and organizes the data for the front-end. It takes the thread about 10 minutes to read xml and organize the data. So I want to change the architecture a little bit. I want to run the separate thread on a standalone java process and take care of reading xml instead of spawning a thread in the web app.

The solution that I am running into is how I should have the webapp pick up the modified data (which is about 100MB when I serialize the object to a file) which is organized in the standlone java process. Do I still need to have a separate thread to deserialize the object serialized from the standalone java process?

I'd appreciated about different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Where does this giant xml come from?

Without knowing any other facts, I wonder why this giant XML isn't a database, and your backend isn't a relatively simple program to query the database.

Comment: we read the xml from a remote location once a day. This is the current architecture. I would like to change a little bit per release. For now, I want to change without making a big impact on the current architecture.

Comment: dragging 2gb of xml around, every day, definitely sounds like a bad idea.  Databases are the most likely replacement for your process.